# Default number of executors and cores for spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark

If I run a spark program in spark shell, is it possible that the program can hog the entire hadoop cluster for hours?

usually there is a setting called num-executors and executor-cores.

```
spark-shell --driver-memory 10G --executor-memory 15G --executor-cores 8
```

but if they are not specified and I just run "spark-shell"... will it consume the entire cluster? or are there reasonable defaults.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default values for most configuration properties can be found in the [Spark Configuration documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#available-properties). For the configuration properties on your example, the defaults are:

> - spark.driver.memory = 1g
> - spark.executor.memory = 1g
> - spark.executor.cores = 1 in YARN mode, all the available cores on the worker in standalone mode.

Additionally, you can override these defaults by creating the file`$SPARK-HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf` with the properties you want (as described [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties)). Then, if the file exists with the desired values, you don't need to pass them as arguments to the `spark-shell` command.

Comment: what about the number of yarn containers.

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch I am not very familiar with Spark on YARN, but you can probably find what your need at the Spark's [Running on YARN documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#configuration)